# HTML - Auto stretching height of the body element beyond 100%

Tags: html, css, height

I'm having really hard times adjusting the layout for a website, and hopefully someone could help. The issue is that the body with a height of 100% takes the browser's height, but it doesn't extend beyond as per children elements. So for example in the following layout, the footer is over the .second div. The goal is to have the .first taking the full height of the browser and keep the order as it is.

100vh - is not an option due to mobile issues, hence please let me know if this is doable with 100%

Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Document</title>
   <style>
       html, body{
         min-height: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           background-color:blue;
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;

       }

       .wrapper{
           height: 100%;
           background-color: yellow;
       }

       .main{
           height:100%;
           background-color: red;
       }

       .first{
           height: 100%;
           background-color: green;
       }

       .second{

           background-color:brown;
       }
       .footer{
           background: black;
       }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="main">
           <div class="first">
               First Page
           </div>
           <div class="second">
               Second Page
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="footer">
           Footer
       </div>
       
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does the `.first` need to be 100% also or is that just for demonstration?

Comment: .first needs to be 100%. Others not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting `height: 100%` it's going to be 100%, no more, no less.

If you change it to `min-height`, it's going to be 100% or more.

**Note** that I changed `.first` to `100vh`, since `100%` doens't work with `min-height`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      min-height: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .main {
      min-height: 100%;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .first {
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .second {
      background-color: brown;
    }
    
    .footer {
      background: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="first">
        First Page
      </div>
      <div class="second">
        Second Page
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively if you want `first page` and `second page` to be 100% then you can simply put them on the same level as the footer (I removed the `.main`)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      min-height: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .main {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .first {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .second {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: brown;
    }
    
    .footer {
      background: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">
      First Page
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Second Page
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Yes, 100% doesn't work on .first, and I don't get it why. Also, 100vh as mentioned previously won't work for me, I still need to accomplish this by using %.

Comment: Generally yes, but what would be the workaround if first age and second page wouldn't be on the same level as footer, but in main ?

Comment: you could put `overflow: auto` on main, but then you get a second scrollbar. You could probably get it to work using absolute positioning but it seems like a lot of effort if you can get it done in a simple way

Comment: That's right. Tried this already... and many other options. Don't want to make it too complicated. Should be simple and compatible. I'll mark your answer as a solution, as it's best so far. Thanks again for jumping on this.